# Laravel route not found with HTTPS from AWS

Tags: php, apache, laravel, amazon-web-services, https

I just upgraded my HTTP to HTTPS through AWS(ACM) with ELB.
My folder structure is like this,

```
htdocs-
    -index.html
    -myproject(laravel starts here)
      -index.php
      -folder(it contains config and all other folders)
```

Now without HTTPS Redirect code it works perfectly,
but as soon as i add this code which is provided by AWS ACM my landing page comes perfectly but next route gives 404 error.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

My laravel webpage starts from,

https://www.spontieapp.com/mobile

my httpd.conf content is ,
https://pastebin.com/ArUDP6Xg

my .htaccess is ,
https://pastebin.com/wU72Zbau

.htaccess is present under /mobile folder

Please assist on resolving it .
Thanks

Comment: is you'r already setup the .inv file to https url too?

Comment: .inv file ? are you talking about .env file  then yes i have changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
```

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

> ... you will need to ensure that you place this in a .htaccess file in the root of the site you want to apply it against, and to make sure you have the appropriate AllowOverride configuration in your httpd.conf

Comment: where should i add this code , i have httpd.conf for the apache(wamp) server then i have .htaccess for laravel folder project ?

Comment: Updated answer - place in .htaccess file in the root of the site

Comment: I added allowoverrite all in directory tag and removed the above virtualhost code from the https.conf and added your the code given by you it gives me error too many redirects

Comment: Can you add your httpd.conf & .htaccess content to the question? You can use something like pastebin to dump the entire content.

Comment: @neuromater  i have updated the answer with pastebin dump

Comment: You have some conflicting logic in there. Try using this for your .htaccess: https://pastebin.com/BKDy9ScR

Comment: What happenend?

Comment: nothing changed the sam ethink Route Not Found Error